# Passing an object through a link_to command to be referenced in the model#new page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I'm creating a basic loyalty card application, with model Merchant and Loyaltycard. In the merchant#show view I have this line

```
<%=link_to 'New Loyalty card', new_loyaltycard_path(:merchant_id=>1) %>
```

I'm trying to pass the merchant ID to the loyaltycard#new view so it will be automatically selected as the merchant for that card. In loyaltycard#_form (which gets called by loyaltycard#new) I have the lines

```
  <%if @merchant%>
  <%= f.hidden_field :merchant_id, :value => @merchant.id %>
  <%else%>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :merchant_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :merchant_id %>
  </div>
  <%end%>
```

But I keep getting and error that says can't call id for class Nil. Is there a better way of doing this?

Here is the controller code for loyaltycard

```
  def new
    @loyaltycard = Loyaltycard.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @loyaltycard }
    end
  end

  # GET /loyaltycards/1/edit
  def edit
    @loyaltycard = Loyaltycard.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /loyaltycards
  # POST /loyaltycards.json
  def create
    @loyaltycard = Loyaltycard.new(params[:loyaltycard])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @loyaltycard.save
        format.html { redirect_to @loyaltycard, notice: 'Loyaltycard was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @loyaltycard, status: :created, location: @loyaltycard }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @loyaltycard.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The error is

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

Comment: Would you provide the error message and controller code? My bet is the problem is in controller? You should have sth like this in it: @merchant = Merchant.where(:id => merchant_id) and of course Merchant with id == 1 should exist in database.

Comment: I added the info you requested.. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do in your `new` action is using the `params[:merchant_id]` to look up and set `@merchant`

```
@merchant = Merchant.find(params[:merchant_id])
```

Then your code should work, without that, @merchant is nil, and you can't call the method `:id` on `nil`

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting variable @merchant anywhere in your controller, but you use it the view.